# Date format for PHP sorting with Mysql (Datepicker)

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using DatePicker to allow users to add events into a calendar db table but I want to be able to let other users search the database and pick dates between 2 values, so I was wondering what the best date format would be for this as at the moment it's not ordering them correctly (at the moment I'm using d-m-Y). Would you have to put it in as a timestamp and then decode it with php to format it in the website or is there an easier way?

Comment: Use `{ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }` when creating the `datepicker()` (if you want to save the hassle of exploding/re-sorting etc)!

Comment: Thanks @MackieeE, I've done that but how do I change the format back to a more readable format when I output it on the browser, such as 23 Aug 2013?

Comment: When you're echoing it back out to the Browser, use: `date( 'd-m-Y', strtotime( $row["date"] ));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's default format for dates is YYYY-MM-DD ([ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). If you work with your dates in that format you can use MySQL's default sorting to order them properly for you.

Comment: Will this sorting work even if the column isn't set to date? What I want to be able to do afterwards is to re-format the date in the column to something more readable, such as 26 Sept 2013

Comment: If you're still in the development phase, restructure that table column to be datetime! Otherwise you'll find trying to use any DATE queries at Database level a complete pain!

Comment: To expand on that, formatting dates is quick and easy to in both MySQL and PHP but only when the dates are in a standard format. Once you use a non-standard format *everything* becomes much more difficult.

Comment: So change it to datetime and then insert as `{ dateFormat: 'yymmdd' }`, no dashes?

Comment: I *think* that should be `{ dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd' }`. I don't have to work with datepicker often so I am not completely sure of the syntax. But you want the full four digit year, two digit month, and tow digit day with dashed in between them.

Comment: Thanks @JohnConde - I've just tried it without the dashes and all seems to be working well when inputting into the table

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats I don't know why they decided to use 'yy-mm-dd' either! But that's the jQuery UI team for you ;]

Comment: I've played around with this and used the dates in the format suggested and everything works fine when ordering. I then used @MackieeE solution to echo it back in a more readable format - Thanks guys